# Can Tasmota be made to send regular telementry over HTTPS on an ESP32 board?

Tags: https, tasmota

I typically use tasmota to send MQTT messages for (for example) temperature sensors to a host on my LAN - and I then have something listening to MQTT and processing the messages - however I now need to monitor something that is not attached to my LAN, and I am hoping to avoid the complexities of running a publicly accessible MQTT server or other complex intermediary.

Is it possible to use Tasmota to read a (DS18B20) temperature sensor and periodically send an HTTPS post with the sensor data [ to a given URL ] - ie instead of sending data using MQTT, sending it over HTTPS - and if so how would I do it?